# Component connected to withRouter not receiving correct match properties

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having some trouble getting the correct match properties to show in my component connected to `withRouter`

My router map looks like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/start/:short_code/*" render={() => <div>Magic</div>} />
      <Route path="/events" component={EventsPage} exact/>
      <Route path="/events/:auction_code" />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
    <MainMenu />
    <LoginPage />
    <HoldersDrawer />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In my `HomePage` component I have it wrapped in both `withRouter` and `redux`

`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage));`

However, anywhere I attempt to access `this.props.match` I am only seeing

```
{
    isExact:false,
    params:{},
    path:"/",
    url:"/"
}
```

Even if I have set my URL to one of the routes I've outlined

The home page has a QR scanner on it and I want that active no matter which route the user is on, but I also want to be able to access the current route the user is on, on the `HomePage`
For instance, the user can navigate to `events/auction_code` and when they perform and action I need to be able to pass the relevant `auction_code` to the API call said action calls, currently I have to parse that out of the current location pathname data. It would be nice if I could just get it from the `match.params` object.

Can someone see something I may be doing wrong here that would cause this issue?

Comment: Why do you want the match params in the home page, can you please specify your use case

Comment: I updated my router to match what I've just done. I moved my `HomePage` component into an index `Route` component and my app still is working normall (not sure what made me think I needed it outside) and removed the `withRouter` binding. I added some extra information near the bottom to explain what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

The reason that withRouter doesn't provide you the match props of the matched Route is because withRouter gives you access to the `history` object’s properties and the closest `<Route>'s match` and in your case the `HomePage` doesn't have any closest matched Route.

You could achieve what you need by passing on the handler to the Routed component and lifting the action up to the Component that renders the Route. Something like

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and defining App to have handlers like

```
class App extends React.Component {
    handlerFunction = (match) => {
       //your action based on match here
    }

    render() {
       return (
         <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
              <Route path="/start/:short_code/*" render={() => <div>Magic</div>} />
              <Route path="/events" render={(props) => <EventsPage handler={this.handlerFunction} {...props}/>} exact/>
              <Route path="/events/:auction_code" />
              <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
            <MainMenu />
            <LoginPage />
            <HoldersDrawer />
        </div>
       )
    }
}
```